# Candidate template ignored because template argument could not be inferred

Tags: c++, templates

What is wrong with the following piece of code?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename K>
struct A {
    struct X { K p; };
    struct Y { K q; };
};

template<typename K>
void foo(const typename A<K>::X& x, const typename A<K>::Y& y) {
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A<float>::X x;
    A<float>::Y y;
    foo(x, y);  
}
```

clang gives the following error message:

```
17:2: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
        foo(x, y);      
        ^~~
10:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'K'
void foo(const typename A<K>::X& x, const typename A<K>::Y& y) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The argument `K` in `const typename A<K>::X` is *not deducible*. Basically, everything left of a `::` is not deducible (if `::` separates a nested-name).

It's trivial to see why it makes no sense to ask for deduction by running through this thought experiment:

```
struct A { typedef int type; }
struct B { typedef int type; }

template <typename T> void foo(typename T::type);

foo(5);   // is T == A or T == B ??
```

There's no one-to-one mapping from types to nested types: Given any type (such as `int`), there could be many ambient types of which it is a nested type, or there needn't be any.

Answer (score 11):

```
template<typename K>
void foo(const typename A<K>::X& x, const typename A<K>::Y& y) {
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
```

`K` cannot been deduced, since it's in `non-deduced` context.

n3337 14.8.2.5/4

> In certain contexts, however,
> the value does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template arguments that
> were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. **If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced
> contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails**.

n3337 14.8.2.5/5

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using `::` for referencing a nested struct is not correct. The right way is to use `A<K>.x`, where `x` is a member of type `X<K>`. But for this to work, you need to declare two members `x`, `y` of type  `X<K>` and `Y<K>`, respectively.

Secondly, I think that a good practice is to separate the template declarations of `struct X` and `struct Y` from the declaration of struct A in order to avoid the nested struct declaration.

In short, I would rewrite your code as followings:

```
template<class K>
struct X {
    K p;
};

template<class K>
struct Y {
    K q;
};

template<class K>
struct A {
    X<K> x;
    Y<K> y;
};

template<class K>
void foo(const X<K>& x, const Y<K>& y) {
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A<float> a;
    foo(a.x, a.y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing nested types versus nested fields. You would use `::` for nested types, while you'd use `.` for nested fields.