# Template iterator inside template class, clang cannot infer template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, clang++

I have a template class with a nested template custom iterator (specialized into const/non-const iterators) like this :

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <typename U>
    struct AIterator
    {
        //...
    };

    typename AIterator<T*> iterator;
    typename AIterator<const T*> const_iterator;
};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const typename A<T>::iterator& lhs,
                const typename A<T>::iterator& rhs,)
{
    //...
}

template <typename T>
bool operator!=(const typename A<T>::iterator& lhs,
                const typename A<T>::iterator& rhs,)
{
    //...
}

//idem for const_iterator...
```

But clang can't infer the template parameter :

```
snake_test.cpp:17:68: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('wavelet::Snake<float>::const_iterator' (aka 'Iterator<const float *>') and 'const_iterator' (aka 'Iterator<const float *>'))
        for (wavelet::Snake<float>::const_iterator it = snake.begin(); it != snake.end(); it++)
                                                                       ~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
./snake.hpp:150:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
bool operator!=(const typename Snake<T>::iterator& lhs,
     ^
./snake.hpp:164:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
bool operator!=(const typename Snake<T>::const_iterator& lhs,
     ^
1 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong ? How to properly implement custom iterators for template classes ?

Comment: For one, your reference tags are on the wrong side of your arguments. ex: `lhs&` should be `&lhs`, etc. The trailing commas after the `rhs` arguments aren't helping much either.

Comment: Thanks ! I was cooking while writing this question so I wrote it fast therefore it could remain some typos. ;-)

Comment: Have you tried defining `operator==` and `operator!=` inside of `A`?

Comment: @More Axes : Yes I have, but clang "told" me theses operators needed 2 arguments and not 3 (it found 3 because of "implicit" this).

Comment: Template parameters in a nested-name-specifier of a function template function parameter are in a non-deduced context. I.e. in `A<T>::iterator`, `T` cannot be deduced.

Comment: That's because lhs is implicit (ąs `this`) when you're defining them inside. Try removing one of the arguments from the type signature.

Comment: +1 to dyp. totally answered my previous lack of clarity to your problem .

Comment: @MoreAxes Boolean operators are in general implemented as non-member function. I don't know why but (as always in C++) there must be a good reason. Plus if I implemented them as member function I should have defined them inside AIterator not A.

Comment: @matovitch *Binary* operators (two operands) are implemented as non-member functions because of symmetry. This allows identical conversion for the LHS and RHS (consider `struct BigInt { BigInt(int); }; BigInt b; 42 == b`) and is "cleaner" because typically such operators are commutative anyway, meaning LHS and RHS have the same significance.

Comment: @dyp Thanks. Hope it will stick in my head this time. (authoritative argument is much simpler to remember)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possibly easiest and cleanest solution is to use non-member friend functions defined inside the class body:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <typename U>
    struct AIterator
    {
        friend bool operator==(AIterator const& lhs, AIterator const& rhs)
        { /* implement here */ }
    };

    typename AIterator<T*> iterator;
    typename AIterator<const T*> const_iterator;
};
```

This will create a non-member function for each specialization of `AIterator`. You cannot provide the definition outside for this non-member function, as far as I know -- it is not a function template, but a proper function for each specialization. So you can only define a fixed set of specializations in the global namespace.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why nested types are in a non-deduced context. It seems at first glance there's no information in the type that associates it with its surrounding scope; possibly this has to do with typedefs, which are transparent. I do not see why associating information about the surrounding scope should be impossible, but deducing it would probably lead to subtle problems.

Comment: Thanks ! I was thinking about friend too. :-)

Comment: [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566228/candidate-template-ignored-because-template-argument-could-not-be-inferred) was very helpful!: basically there isn't a one-to-one correspondence from a type to its enclosing type, so it's not always guaranteed that the enclosing type is   is even deducable.