# Can a templated function be a template argument to another function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I thought I'd benchmark some sorting algorithms, but I must be doing templates incorrectly:

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
void dummysort(ForwardIterator begin_it, ForwardIterator end_it)
{
    // pretend to use these and sort stuff
    ++begin_it;
    ++end_it;
}

template<typename SortFunc>
void benchmark(const char* name, SortFunc sort_func, std::vector<int> v)
{
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    sort_func(v.begin(), v.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> first = {3, 2, 1};

    benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort, first);
}
```

### Error

```
10:48 $ clang -std=c++14 tmp.cpp
tmp.cpp:30:5: error: no matching function for call to 'benchmark'
    benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort, first);
    ^~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:20:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'SortFunc'
void benchmark(const char* name, SortFunc sort_func, std::vector<int> v)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

### Compiler Info

```
10:47 $ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/
```

If I "untemplate" `dummysort`, it works.

```
void dummysort(std::vector<int>::iterator begin_it, std::vector<int>::iterator end_it)
```

### Question

Is there a way I can make it work generically, or, if not, can someone please give me a good explanation or thought experiment similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12566268/2958070)?

Comment: You cannot pass a template, only a function. You should be able to write `benchmark("bubblesort", &dummysort<int>, first);`. If you want the `int` to be deduced you can do that too by writing a wrapper that gives you the correct overload based on the type.

Comment: @nwp So I can't write a benchmark that takes a generic sort function which is argument compatible with std::sort?

Comment: @nwp - do you mean `&dummysort<std::vector<int>::iterator>` ?

Comment: @Ben - take in count that, i C++, a template function isn't a function: is a recipe to construct a function; when you pass `dummisort`, you pass the recipe, not a functions; if you want pass a function, you have to explicit the type (as suggested by nwp); but there is another way... I'll try to write an example and prepare an answer.

Comment: @max66 Yeah, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two minor comments: You should pass the `v` parameter to `benchmark` by reference `std::vector<int> &v` and not by value `std::vector<int> v`, since vectors are expensive objects to construct. And `std::endl` is unnecessary with the standard streams; instead of

```
std::cout << "Value of the variable:" << std::endl;
std::cout << variable << std::endl;
```

you can just write

```
std::cout << "Value of the variable:\n";
std::cout << variable << '\n';
```

Which is both a lot less verbose and faster (not that it matters for the trivial case here).

To answer your question, no, the compiler would not be able to infer `dummysort`'s template parameter in this case, so you would have to write it `dummysort<std::vector<int>::iterator>`. But there are ways you can simplify it:

1) If your compiler supports C++14 [variable templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) you can declare

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto vecdummysort = dummysort<typename std::vector<T>::iterator>;
```

And then use it like

```
benchmark("bubblesort", vecdummysort<int>, first);
```

2a) With C++11 you can create an [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
template<typename T>
using veciter = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
```

Which lets you use `dummysort` like

```
benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort<veciter<int>>, first);
```

2b) For the same `vecdummysort` function as in example #1:

```
template<typename T>
void vecdummysort(veciter<T> first, veciter<T> last) {dummysort(first, last);}
```

3) You could also change the call to `sort_func` in `benchmark` to use raw pointers instead of iterators, so

```
sort_func(v.data(), v.data() + v.size());
```

Instead of

```
sort_func(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Which means you would be able to use `benchmark` like

```
benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort<int*>, first);
```

4) You can change the interface of `dummysort` to take the collection itself as the argument instead of iterators, which sacrifices a tiny bit of flexibility (e.g. if you wanted to sort only part of the collection, or use reverse iterators, and so forth) for a less verbose and more ergonomic interface

```
template<typename Collection>
void dummysort(Collection &c)
{
    auto first = std::begin(c);
    auto last = std::end(c);
}
```

Usage:

```
// benchmark()
sort_func(v);
// main()
benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort<std::vector<int>>, first);
```

Comment: I want the container passed by value because I want to call the benchmark multiple times with different sort functions and I don't want one benchmark to affect the next one.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could specialize my functions at the call site and use alias templates like that. This answer lets me write my sort functions swappably with std::sort, and I'll just have to type a little more in the benchmark

Comment: @Ben You still should pass the container by reference (and [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) it between benchmarks) for two reasons. 1) Under the hood, dynamic allocations acquire and release mutexes, and may trigger a page fault, which both can throw off a benchmark in a low-level non-GC'd lang like C++ (you could instead pass a `std::array` by value), 2) If the compiler can prove no observed side effects depend on the vector's existence, it can remove it and the sorting as dead code! Conveniently, `std::shuffle`'s use of a RNG is such a side effect.

Comment: Other observed side effects include, before and after every sort, printing every element of the vector, or assigning every element to a `volatile` variable. (You need to do every element because if you just printed, say, `v.back()`, the compiler might deduce it only needs to find the maximum and doesn't need to sort the rest). But I think `std::shuffle` is cleaner (make sure to do it before the first benchmark as well as the others), and probably works better preventing optimizing compiler cleverness where it inlines then constant-folds the sorting algorithm at compile-time.

Comment: I'd appreciate you looking at [the start of my benchmark code](https://gist.github.com/bbkane/d86276178f339ee79af1577ba19563d8) . This is before I decided to pass iterators to the sort functions. Anyway, I don't start the benchmark until after the function starts and I print it before and after, so I hope I'm safe on the page fault front. I'd be more worried about any effects of std::shuffle meaning I'm testing different data

Comment: If you want to force a flush of the output buffer you should use `std::endl`.

Comment: @Ben With a hard disk, a page fault means the reader head must physically seek to the location of the new page, which means a slowdown for the next few hundreds of millions of clock cycles. I'm not sure if there's a similar effect with SSDs, which have no moving parts, but in any event cache effects can often make algorithms working on dynamically-allocated data structures hard to benchmark consistently. I'll leave a more detailed comment on your gist.

Comment: @RayHamel Thanks, I really appreciate it

Comment: @Ben [Here you are.](https://gist.github.com/bbkane/d86276178f339ee79af1577ba19563d8#gistcomment-2254616) You're very  welcome, happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

As explained by nwp, a template function isn't a function; is only a recipe to construct a function.

So you can't pass the recipe

```
benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort, first);
```

but you can do it explicating the type an constructing a function from the recipe; I mean

```
benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort<std::vector<int>::iterator>, first);
```

Works but I find it a little ugly.

I propose you another solution: instead of a template function, construct a class (or struct) with a template `operator()` in it; something like

```
struct dummySort
 {
   template <typename FI>
   void operator() (FI begin_it, FI end_it)
    {
      ++begin_it;
      ++end_it; 
    }
 };
```

In this way you can call `benchmark()` passing an object of this type without explicating the type of the iterator: it's the call to operator inside of `benchmark()` that select the right type and construct the right operator.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct dummySort
 {
   template <typename FI>
   void operator() (FI begin_it, FI end_it)
    { ++begin_it; ++end_it; }
 };

template <typename SortFunc>
void benchmark (char const * name, SortFunc sort_func, std::vector<int> v)
 {
   std::cout << name << std::endl;
   sort_func(v.begin(), v.end());
 }

int main()
 {
   std::vector<int> first = {3, 2, 1};

   benchmark("bubblesort", dummySort{}, first);
 }
```

Comment: One can also delay the instantiation of the templated function by wrapping it in a lambda:
`benchmark("bubblesort", dummysort<std::vector<int>::iterator>, first);
`
can be replaced by 
`benchmark("bubblesort", [](auto beg, auto end){dummysort(beg, end);}, first);`
More informations about that can be found here: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/01/overloaded-functions-stl/

Comment: @sv90 Holy cow thats neat

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways around this problem.

1. You could explicitly specify the template arguments for `dummysort` or you could `static_cast` it to the appropriate function pointer type. This, to me, is a pretty bad solution as it locks into a specific overload choice rather than relying on the language's overload rules. If you change other arguments or types, you could get (best-case) broken code or (worst-case) code that works but does something unexpected
2. You could lift your function template to be a function *object* that has a call operator template:

   ```
   struct dummysort_t {
       template <typename ForwardIterator>
       void operator()(ForwardIterator begin_it, ForwardIterator end_it) const {
           /* ... */
       }
   } constexpr dummysort{}; // in C++17, also mark inline
   ```

   This allows you to just directly pass in `dummysort` to your function templates everywhere with the same expected behavior. The downsides to this solution are if you don't own `dummysort`, this is of course a non-starter, and if you use `dummysort` as a customization point, you need to do quite a bit more work to get this to have the expected behavior.
3. You could wrap it in a lambda. Since we're copying iterators, the simple form just works:

   ```
   [](auto b, auto e) { dummysort(b, e); }
   ```

   This delays template instantiation for `dummysort` until the other function template actually invokes it. This gives you the exact behavior you want, and will work in all situations (and fixes the issues with #2). More generally, this pattern should be used like:

   ```
   #define OVERLOADS_OF(name) [&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(name(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)) { return name(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
   ```

   with which you would pass:

   ```
   OVERLOADS_OF(dummysort)
   ```

   which for this particular case is overkill, but is more generally useful.